# Como crear relaciones en Django

Tags: json, django

Hola estoy creando una appWeb, utilizando el framwork Django de python, tengo varios jsons con información que quiero volcar en mi bbdd, y tengo que crear el models.py para dichos jsons, por ejemplo este:

```
"A": {
      "version": "6.24.1",
      "id": "",
      "key": "",
      "name": "",
      "title": "",
      "blurb": "",
      "info": {
        "attack": 8,
        "defense": 4,
        "magic": 3,
        "difficulty": 4
      }
```

Lo que no tengo claro es como puedo crear por ejemplo el campo

```
info
```

que dentro de el tiene varios campos como:

```
"attack": 8,
"defense": 4,
"magic": 3,
"difficulty": 4
```

Por el momento mi models.py es de la siguiente forma;

```
class Champ(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    id  = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    version = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    blurb = models.TextField()
```

Alguien sabe la forma correcta de representar por ejemplo el campo info? en el models.py de Django?

Comment: info es relacion 1 a muchos , por lo tanto cuaando crees info son los valores mas el foreign key de Champ

Comment: Perdona mi ignorancia, puedes explicar un poco mas lo de "cuando crees info, son los valores mas el foreing key de champ?"
te refieres a que tengo que crear otra tabla con esos campos i relacionarla con champ?

Comment: que version de django trabajas?

Comment: mi version es 1.11.17

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suponiendo que **`Champ`** esta de la siguiente forma:

```
class Champ(models.Model):
    version = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    blurb = models.TextField()
```

Debes crear el modelo **`Info`** y agregarle la relación

```
class Info(models.Model):
    attack = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    defense  = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    magic = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    difficulty = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    champ = models.ForeignKey(Champ, related_name='champ')
```

y en tu view para obtener los datos debe hacer algo como:

```
Champ.objects.select_related('info').get(id=5)
```

> para saber mas sobre las relaciones puedes ver la [Documentación
>   Oficial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)

---

**Adicional**

Si quieres verificar como te devuelven los datos no cargues la pagina puedes usar [el shell de Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/), el comando es el siguiente:

```
python manage.py shell
```

Una vez adentro del shell de Django debes agregar el import y lo que necesitas:

```
from [tu_proyecto].models import Champ
Champ.objects.select_related('info').get(id=5)
```

Comment: perfecto, me lo imagine así pero no lo tenia nada claro, muchísimas gracias por la ayuda compañero

Comment: voy a agregar algo mas para que sepas como hacer un test

Comment: Ostia tio eres un crack.

Muchas gracias por el esfuerzo de ayudar a un servidor con tan grata información.