# Django - Template muestra dato en blanco - 2 modelos unidos por FK

Tags: django, django-models

Error al mostrar id de averia de vehículo en template.
Averia y vehículo están unidos por FK. Al rellenar formulario de Avería se selecciona un vehículo (eso funciona bien). No me devuelve valor cuando al listar los vehículos, quiero ver el id de avería.

**Modelo1:**

```
class Averia(models.Model):
    averia = models.CharField('Averia',max_length=50)
    vehiculo = models.ForeignKey(Vehiculo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Modelo2:**

```
class Vehiculo(models.Model):
    marca = models.CharField('Marca',max_length=50,null=True, blank=True)
    matricula = models.CharField('Matricula',max_length=50,null=True, blank=True)
```

**View:**

```
def vehiculo_list(request):
    vehiculos = Vehiculo.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'vehiculos/vehiculos_list.html', {'vehiculos': vehiculos})
```

**Template:**

```
{% for vehiculo in vehiculos %}
        {{ vehiculo.marca }}
        {{ vehiculo.matricula }}
        {{ averia.id }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: En el modelo vehículo no existe el campo avería allí es el problema

Comment: Pero avería ya tiene campo averia y están unidos por FK. ¿No se puede tomar el dato id avería correpondiente a ese vehículo?

Comment: [mira esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/266577/28035)+

Comment: Sucede que en el ejemplo que me mandas hace una búsqueda concreta cuyo id es 5. Yo lo hago mediante una lista y debe mostrar todo. Posiblemente me confunda, pero creo que eso no me funcionaría. Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recuerda que hay una relación de **uno a muchos** entre los modelos o tablas `Averia` y `Vehiculo`:

> Una **averia** no puede tener mas de un **vehiculo**, pero un **vehiculo**
>   puede tener varias **averias**.

Entonces ya que un vehículo puede tener varias **averias**, tienes que acceder a las averias relacionadas, de la siguiente manera, no como lo intentabas hacer (esto se conoce como "relación inversa" o "relación hacia atrás", mas detalles en la [documentación de Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)):

```
>>> vehiculo = Vehiculo.objects.get(...)
>>> vehiculo.averia_set.all()
<QuerySet [...]>
```

Entonces lo de obtener el `id` de una averia especifica no podrás hacerlo, pues así creaste la relación.

Y a lo mejor podrías hacer algo así en tu template:

```html
{% for vehiculo in vehiculos %}
    {{ vehiculo.marca }}
    {{ vehiculo.matricula }}

    <h3>Averias de {{ vehiculo.marca }}</h3>
    {% for averia in vehiculo.averia_set.all %}
        {{ averia.averia }} - {{ averia.id }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

---

Por otra parte podrías hacer la relación al "contrario", es decir:

> Un **vehiculo** no puede tener mas de un **averia**, pero un **averia**
>   puede tener varios **vehiculos**.

```
class Vehiculo(models.Model):
    ...
    averia = models.ForeignKey(Averia, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

De esta manera si podrás hacer lo que intentaste en tu template, pero no se si eso es lo que quieres exactamente.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: no conocia eso de la relacion inversa.. magnifico!

Comment: @JackNavaRow algo genial de Django!

Comment: Gracias una vez más Julio Cesar. Entonces, de esta manera que propones, ¿podría como actualmente, al crear nueva avería (en un formulario) seleccionar el vehículo (de entre todos los que hay)?

Comment: @julian no te entiendo, explícame con mas detalles xD